# GET never finishes for url with Umlaut ü

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

`GET` failed to scrape this website... why?

```
require(httr)
GET("http://www.atelco.de/1546/Bügeln.search") # Never finishes
GET(URLencode("http://www.atelco.de/1546/Bügeln.search")) # works fine
```

I tried with other websites that have **ü** in their URL:

```
GET("http://www.bosch-home.com/de/produkte/bügeln.html")
```

To me it seams like a bug. But I don't know what it is. Am I missing something here?

My Session-Info is:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] httr_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.1.1      magrittr_1.5  tools_3.2.2   curl_0.9.4    stringi_1.0-1 stringr_1.0.0 XML_3.98-1.3
```

Comment: Looks like a curl/httr problem. Please file a bug.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily rule out R by testing the same URL with the `curl` command line utility:

```
curl -Lv http://www.atelco.de/1546/Bügeln.search
```

This looks like a server side configuration issue. They are running some custom Tomcat/Java web application that keeps redirecting to the same URL:

```
* Connected to www.atelco.de (81.7.220.137) port 80 (#0)
> GET /1546/Bügeln.search HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.atelco.de
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=46E977E738A6DBC8BD0EB8084912163F.www1; Domain=.atelco.de; Path=/
< Location: http://www.atelco.de/1546/Bügeln.search
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 12:17:43 GMT
```

As you found out yourself, you can work around the problem by escaping the URL, but this should not be needed nowadays.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "should not be needed nowadays"? Bottom line this is a curl-bug?

Comment: No, it's a server bug. It works fine for the bosch-home.com server, right?

Comment: Hi Jeroen, this is what i understand. But as i do not own the page i can not fix this. So to me scraping the web, the bug is that `httr::GET` or `curl` hangs and does not throw an error that i can catch. So my question is how do i get `httr` to report the server-bug?